# Managing common dependencies across plugins

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, plugins

I have implemented a springboot application that can be extended by loading plugins into it. The plugins are created by extending from a common interface specified in my library (LibA) and loaded into the springboot application using Java SPI. Because of this, LibA is a dependency to the springboot application.

There are some common libraries (LibB, LibC) that are used by the plugins which are not part of the springboot application.

The current implementation requires each plugin to be a fat jar containing LibA, LibB, LibC and because of this the versions of the libs need to be the same otherwise there will be issues (such as method not found) while loading these plugins.

I would like to have these common libraries as part of the springboot application and have the plugins refer to the versions in the application. Doing this could result in smaller jars and also ensure the consistency of the version of the libraries used by the plugins.

I could specify LibA, LibB and LibC as dependencies of the springboot application and have the plugins remove them from it's jar and things might work but this would still require the versions to be specified in the plugin's build.gradle.

**What I want to know is how to have something similar to the way springboot specifies and provides it's dependencies. Other ways to manage this is also appreciated. I'm using gradle as the build tool.**

**Current**

**App (LibA), plugins (LibA, LibB, LibC)**

**What i need**

**App (LibA, LibB, LibC), plugins (just refer to the versions in app)**

I'm unsure if this is the correct channel to post this question, let me know if it's not suitable.

Comment: How about Java Platform Plugin https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html ?

Comment: Yup, that's the approach i chosen in the end. So i made a project with no srcs and a only a build.gradle that uses Gradle's java platform to specify the required common dependencies and versions. This project is then used in the consuming project and the dependency versions are verified to be the same. Thanks a lot for your comment.